# isc-dhcpd static ip within range

Tags: isc-dhcp

I have a isc-dhcpd server with dhcp-range 10.0.0.10 - 10.0.0.20.
There is also a device connected with static ip 10.0.0.10.
What would happen when a client with dynamic ip connects to the network?

What if I changed the static ip to 10.0.0.20, and connect the client with the dynamic ip?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

So you have a subnet declaration... Presumably
`10.0.0.0/8` (or `/24`, I suppose).

And you have a subnet range inside the subnet declaration, of 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.20

Like:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.20
}
```

And then you have a static IP declaration, presumably like

```
group {
host static-host {
    hardware ethernet 1a:6b:6a:32:a5:01;
    fixed-address 10.0.0.10;
  }
}
```

So the next available address that the DHCPd knows about is `.11`

The dhcp server will never hand out an address to a dynamic client where the `fixed-address` is specified elsewhere with a `hardware ethernet` address.

You should be able to change the static-host's declaration to change the `fixed-address`, restart the dhcp server, and then rebind any dynamic clients.  They address may change (if they had either `.10` or `.20`), but if they were in the range `.11` to `.19`, their address may not change.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the DHCP server will assign a client an IP address that is *already in use*, the answer is no. At least not for the ISC server, per their [documentation](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-41-manual-pages-dhcpdconf#IP%20ADDRESS%20CONFLICT%20PREVENTION).

The DHCP server will check to see if an address is in use by using an ICMP echo packet before assigning it to a client. This allows a client with a self-assigned static IP address in your DHCP scope to peacefully exist on the network.

A well-administrated network will use DHCP reservations in cases like these.

If you are asking if a device with a self-assigned (static) IP address will connect to a network where that IP address is currently in use, it depends on the network device. The device should recognize that there is a duplicate IP address on the network, and de-activate the network interface.

However, the device **doesn't have to**. A rogue device could simply try to force itself on the network and cause connection problems for the other device that is using that IP address.